# Kinematics question. A falling object falls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

This is quite bad for me as I'm a third year physics student now, however I'm attempting to go back on my old first year work as a refresher, but I'm completely stuck on a question! Can anyone help?

The question:

> A falling object travels one-fourth of its total distance in the last second of its fall. From what height was it dropped?

I understand the initial velocity is 0, we're dealing with a = g, and I know it'll be some combination of $x=1/2\;gt^2$ and $3/4x=1/2\;g(t-1)^2.$

But for the life of me I can't complete it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hi, k.b! Note that this is not a homework-helping site! please check this question for further specification: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714

Comment: @John Rennie: How do you write this so fast! Is this auto-generated comment?

Comment: You've got the equations right, whatever is left is just the mathematics

Comment: @user36790: It is an auto-generated comment, see http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se for details.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Yes, you accustomed me with this earlier also; this is famous as _Normal-Human_ comment at Math SE.

Comment: @user36790: Well if you're accustomed to the script & my comment (originally it was just me doing that, but others have taken that comment & made it their own as well), why question its origins?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: No, I wasn't accustomed to the script (the sentence in Rennie's comment) I but did know that there can be auto-generated comments. At least I've encountered that at Math SE where it was mentioned in parenthesis that the comment was auto-generated.